# ngClass with multiple conditions false condition not working

Tags: html, angular, ng-class

I'm trying to use [ngClass] with multiple conditions to change the caret of a open/close panel.

Currently the down arrow works flawlessly.
When I click the arrow and the condition changes to false, it changes the icon to a empty box and is not recognizing the correct class name.

```
<i [ngClass]="{'fa fa-caret-up pull-right': isActive4 == true, 
'fa fa-caret-down pull-right': isActive4 == false}"
(click)="section4Click()"></i>
```

The section4Click() changes isActive4 to true/false depending on what it was before.

When I inspect element of the box that shows up after I click the down caret (which works), I get the following class name...

fa-caret-up

instead of...

fa fa-caret-up pull-right

Anyone know why this occurs?  It seems like its doing half the job...
I've also tried just doing isActive4 and !isActive4, and the same happens.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's hard to tell from looking at your code. But you can try this:

```
<i class="fa pull-right" [class.fa-caret-up]="isActive4" [class.fa-caret-down]="!isActive4" (click)="section4Click()"></i>
```

I would also recommend printing the values to see what you get:

```
<p>{{ isActive4 === true }}</p>
```

Comment: Well, that seems to work wonders.  Not sure why in mine it didn't work, but nevertheless, your answer does the job.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This will work.

```
<i class="fa pull-right" [ngClass]="{'fa-caret-up': isActive4 == true, 
'fa-caret-down': isActive4 == false}"
(click)="section4Click()"></i>
```